# .Net Core 3.1 as a standalone Identity Server

Tags: .net-core, jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, encryption-asymmetric

I would like to use a .Net Core 3.1 web app to allow an app (e.g. iPhone or Web Javascript) to authenticate with a username and password and receive a Jason Web Token (JWT) that contains claims about the user... if it succeeds, then the JWT can be sent as a bearer token to an API that would decode and validate the JWT (the token would be asymmetric and use a public/private key pair) and retrieve any claims that are embedded... perhaps a bonus if the app could decode the JWT as well in order to retrieve any claims.

Any thoughts on if this approach is possible? And, if there are any discussions or examples of how this might be done, that would be terrific.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the examples that IdentityServer4 is providing. This sample/quickstart includes the case you are describing. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src

The API needs to be a scope in the IdentityServer4 configuration. It has a connection with the authority (IdentityServer4):

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });
```

The Client, in this example an MVC Client, needs to be a client in IdentityServer4. There are many types of GrantTypes. https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                
                options.Scope.Add("api1");

                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

Hope this helps you out